# In make, how do I run prequisites exactly once?

Tags: makefile

Let's pretend I have two servers A and B that I want to have the ability to deploy to separately and together in Makefile targets. Let's also say there's a preparation step that I want to run exactly once before any deployment, whether it's to one or both. How could I do that?

Here's what I have so far, but it's not DRY.

```
clean:
    # do cleanup stuff

deploy:
    make clean
    ssh $(SERVER) do-remote-deployment-stuff

deploy-to-a:
    deploy SERVER=myservera

deploy-to-b:
    deploy SERVER=myserverb

deploy-all:
    deploy-to-a
    deploy-to-b
```

See how it'd run 'clean' twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using recursion, just put the target you only want to run once as a prerequisite:

```
deploy-to-a: clean
        ...
deploy-to-b: clean
        ...
```

However, your attempt to set SERVER= etc. won't work, and neither will your `deploy-all` rule.  You can't put make targets into make recipes.  You can use pattern rules:

```
SERVERS = A B

A_SERVER = myservera
B_SERVER = myserverb

deploy-all: $(SERVERS:%=deploy-to-%)

deploy-to-%: clean
        ssh $($*_SERVER) do-remote-deployment-stuff

clean:
        # do cleanup stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me about pattern rules. I hadn't seen those.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `clean` target as a dependency for your other targets.  In order to keep it DRY, you could have something like this in your `Makefile`:

```
SERVERLIST = myservera myserverb

.PHONY: clean deploy-all $(SERVERLIST)

clean:
    # do cleanup stuff

$(SERVERLIST): clean
    ssh $@ do-remote-deployment-stuff

deploy-all: $(SERVERLIST)
```

You could define as many servers as you want with the `SERVERLIST` variable.

Running `make -n deploy-all` shows you the commands that will be run:

```
# do cleanup stuff
ssh myservera do-remote-deployment-stuff
ssh myserverb do-remote-deployment-stuff
```

To deploy to just one server, you can run `make myservera`, etc.  You can of course create an "alias" for your server as well:

```
SERVERLIST = my.longservername.com someother.server.somewhere.else.com

myservera: someother.server.somewhere.else.com
```